# NSData properties cannot be queried over an object link

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have model like this:

```
class Session: Object {
    dynamic var token: NSData?
}

class SessionsPool: Object {
    let sessions = List<Session>()
}
```

I can request all sessions (normally there is one or zero) with required token

```
let myToken: NSData = ...
let sessions = self.realm.objects(Session).filter("token == %@", myToken)
```

It works well.

And I would like to request all pools that has at least one session with required token. And I would like to "observe" this request for updates.

```
let myToken: NSData = ...
var pools = self.realm.objects(SessionsPool).filter("ANY sessions.token == %@", myToken)
pools.addNotificationBlock { (change) in
            // Some code
        }
```

But I can't do it due to error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Unsupported operator', 
reason: 'NSData properties cannot be queried over an object link.'
```

So I can use predicates like `token == *someNSData*` or like `ANY sessions.stringToken == *someNSString*`, but not like `ANY sessions.token == *someNSData*`.

What's wrong with NSData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular query type hasn't been implemented yet: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4222

However, your query can be refactored to something that Realm does support:

Replace this: `ANY sessions.token == %@`

With this: `SUBQUERY(sessions, $session, $session.token == %@).@count > 0`